# iOS, PJSIP - Unsuitable transport after IP change

Tags: ios, tcp, sip, voip, pjsip

I am trying to recreate TCP transport after IP change in ringing state. My steps for that are the next:

1. Shutdown an old transport (pjsip_transport_shutdown()).
2. Register again (pjsua_acc_set_registration()).
3. Save a new transport.
4. Reject a call with PJSIP_SC_BUSY_HERE code (pjsua_call_hangup()).

The problem is that when my network changes from 3G to WiFi, an app sends "REGISTER" SIP message from a new ip (WiFi) and after that "BUSY HERE" SIP message from an old ip (3G) (see figure 1). When network changes from WiFi to 3G, the app sends "REGISTER" SIP message from a new ip (3G) and does not send "BUSY HERE" SIP message at all (see figure 2).

It seems that "REGISTER" goes through the new transport and "BUSY HERE" goes through the old transport. I know that the old transport is still here for some time. But why PJSIP uses different transports for these SIP messages?

Thanks in advance,
Igor

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Comment: For TCP, a response must be sent using the same transport where the request came from, as specified by the standard.
And it seems that transaction did not receive transport disconnected event (yet), so it reused the transport.